# How to add custom WCF behavior extension to machine.config

Tags: .net, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010, machine.config

I'm trying to implement my own version of the Custom Behavior shown here: [Using Windows Credentials in WCF-Custom adapter](http://www.codit.eu/blog/2014/03/28/star-using-windows-credentials-in-wcf-custom-adapter/)
 and here: [Impersonate WCF Credentials when calling a WCF Service](http://axonolympus.nl/?page_id=186&post_id=1852&cat_id=6)

BizTalk requires everything to be put in the GAC, which I did by running GacUtil.

I attempted the following changes to machine.config, and I know they didn't work because if I restart the BizTalk Host Instance, I get bizarre errors.

Changed from this:

```
  <section name="extensions" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionsSection, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

To this:

```
  <section name="extensions" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionsSection, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <add name="WindowsCredentialsBehaviour" type="MyApp.Biztalk.WCF.Extensions.ImpersonateBasicCredentialsBehaviour, MyApp.CustomEndpointBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b12735283a466be4" />
  </section>
```

In BizTalk, the Assembly looks like this:

> MyApp.CustomEndpointBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b12735283a466be4"

So I have two main questions:

1. I'm not sure why in the config file there are two names, is one the class or behavior name, and the second is the assembly name?
2. What did I do wrong?

Here are my namespaces:

```
namespace MyApp.Biztalk.WCF.Extensions
{
    public class ImpersonateBasicCredentialsBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
...
namespace MyApp.Biztalk.WCF.Extensions
{
    public class ImpersonateBasicCredentialsBehaviourElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
...
```

I also tried to edit machine.config with the SDK tool: SvcConfigEditor.exe, but it gave this error, so I was left to edit in NotePad++.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define your section (it's already defined). Instead, you just configure your extension in the machine level configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="WindowsCredentialsBehaviour" type="MyApp.Biztalk.WCF.Extensions.ImpersonateBasicCredentialsBehaviour, Asurion.CustomEndpointBehavior" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It will then merge with any application's configuration file that utilizes WCF (`system.serviceModel`). You just need to make sure the type `MyApp.Biztalk.WCF.Extensions.ImpersonateBasicCredentialsBehaviour` is in the assembly available to an application that wants to use WCF (either in GAC or in a private bin path).

Comment: Ah, ok!   I was on the path of a new feature in BT2010: http://www.codit.eu/blog/2012/12/14/how-to-register-wcf-extensions-in-biztalk/ which lets me pull it into BizTalk a different way as well.